# Adding an icon for my exe file with CX_freeze

Tags: python, icons, executable, cx-freeze

I am converting a .py file to a .exe file using cx_freeze. Which is working but I can not seem to change it so that my .exe file has the custom icon I have. This is what I have tried so far:
'''

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./src/"))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("./src/gui/rc/"))

**Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.**

buildOptions = {
    "packages": ["src.gui",
                 "src.qt_models",
                 "src.data",
                 "src.libs",
                 "src.tguiil",
                 "src.graphics"
                 ],
    "includes": ["scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation",
                 "scipy.ndimage._ni_support",
                 "scipy._distributor_init"
                 ],
    "include_files": ["database/"],
    "excludes": []
}

installOptions = {}

bdistOptions = {}

base = None

** Uncomment for GUI applications to NOT show cmd window while running.**
if sys.platform =='win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable(script = 'src/facile.py', base=base, targetName = 'facile.exe', icon = 'facade_logo.ico')
]

setup(name='Facile',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'A platform for generating Python APIs used to control graphical user interfaces.',
      options = {
          "build_exe": buildOptions,
          "install_exe": installOptions,
          "bdist_msi": bdistOptions,
      },
      executables = executables)
```

'''

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Just needed to add relative path to file and add distutils as a package to handle external dependencies:

'''

```
buildOptions = {
    "packages": [
                # Facile sub-packages
                 "src.gui",
                 "src.qt_models",
                 "src.data",
                 "src.libs",
                 "src.tguiil",
                 "src.graphics",

                # External dependencies
                 "distutils"
                 ],
```

'''